# Python split() String into a list with spaces

Tags: python, split

```
user_words = raw_input()
word_list = user_words.split()
user_words = []
for word in word_list:
    user_words.append(word.capitalize())
user_words = " ".join(user_words)
print(user_words)
```

Current Output:

```
Input:
hello  world(two spaces in between)

Output:
Hello World

Desired Output:

Input:
hello  world(two spaces in between)

Output:
Hello  World(two spaces in between)
```

Note: **I want to be able to split the string by spaces, but still have the extra spaces between words in the original string that's inputted by the user.**

Comment: @Vulcan they arent actually ... but he didnt format the question quite right

Comment: `re.sub(r'\w+', lambda m: m.group().capitalize(), 'hello  world')`

Comment: To achieve the result in your example, you can just use `"hello   world".title()` (there are two spaces between hello and world, but they don't show up in comments - duh!)

Comment: Do you need to only support 2 spaces or is it important to keep original format independent of the number of spaces?

Answer (score 11):

If you split using the space character, you'll get extra `''` in your list

```
>>> "Hello  world".split()
['Hello', 'world']
>>> "Hello  world".split(' ')
['Hello', '', 'world']
```

Those generate the extra spaces again after a join

```
>>> ' '.join(['Hello', '', 'world'])
'Hello  world'
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked :) I don't know how i haven't thought about trying that :/ I thought that having a space as an argument to the split() function wouldn't chance anything because i thought it's a space by default.

Comment: @WaleedQutob, it's actually `None` by default, and that triggers special behaviour

Comment: @JohnLaRooy: Technically, empty string isn't None. `'' != None` return True.

Comment: @KevinGuan, I didn't say it was - i meant the the default argument of `str.split()` is `None`. ie. `foo.split(None)` has an identical result to `foo.split()`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy: Oh, you meant that. Actually it is every *empty things*. Such as `\t \n <space>`, etc. So I mean `string.split()` is equals `re.split('\s+', string)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.split` for this and join by the space original string has.

```
user_words = raw_input()
word_list = re.split(r"(\s+)",user_words)
user_words = []
user_words.append(word_list[0].capitalize())
user_words.append(word_list[2].capitalize())
user_words = word_list[1].join(user_words)
print(user_words)
```